# Routine import data from Excel to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database

I know that it's possible to do a manual import of data from an Excel file to a MySQL database.

But is it possible to make this an automated job, a job to be done every 24 hours or 60 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should be looking at your operating system's feature set and not at MySQL if you want a certain task to be executed on a periodic basis.

- On Unix systems, you can have a look at [cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).
- On Windows, there's the [Task Scheduler](https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Usage/How_to_add_a_cron_job_on_Windows.html).

## Concept

The idea is that you have a script (or something else that you can execute) that does exactly what you want **once**. Then tell your operating system by the means of a cron job, a task or similar to run that script every 24 hours, 60 seconds or whatever you like.

## Example

Run the script (or program) `excel_to_db.sh` every 24 hours:

```
0 0 * * * /home/user/scripts/excel_to_db.sh
```

You might want to extend this cron job to redirect the script output (`stdout` and `stderr`) to a file and so on to make this more robust.